# При импорте товара выдаёт ошибку Undefined index: sku (opencart)

Tags: php, opencart

В контроллере сделал импорт модели `$this->load->model('catalog/product');`,
также есть массив данных товара, примерно такой:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'product name1',
        'description' => 'desc product',
        'article' => '431324',
        'model' => 1234
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'product name2',
        'description' => 'desc product',
        'article' => '234524',
        'model' => 65655
    ),
);

    foreach($products as $product){
        $this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($product);
    }
```

выдаёт ошибку - `Undefined index: sku, Undefined index: upc`
Как правильно импортировать товары?

Comment: ясно, метод требует ведь эти атрибуты:  `$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc'])`

Comment: *метод требует массив, а уже в массиве не хватает даных атрибутов.